# Цикл for с пошаговой итерацией на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, циклы

Подскажите, как исправить код, чтобы при каждом клике по btn_refresh запускался цикл и в консоле выводился результат. Т.е. первый клик > выводит "one", второй клик > выводит "two", третий клик > выводит "three".

В данный момент выводятся одновременно 3 варианта.

```
    var btn_refresh=$("#review__content__refresh"),
        fullReviewArray=[0,1,2];

    btn_refresh.click(function(){  
      for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {if(i==0){
             console.log("one");
    }
    else if(i==1){
             console.log("two");
    }
    else if(i==2){
             console.log("three");
    } 
    }//конец for
    });//конец click to btn_refresh
```

Comment: нужно отказаться от цикла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем цикл.

```js
var btn_refresh = $("#review__content__refresh");
btn_refresh.click(function() {
  var counter = this.clickCounter;
  if (counter)
    this.clickCounter = counter + 1;
  else
    this.clickCounter = 1;

  if (this.clickCounter > 3)
    this.clickCounter = 1;

  switch (this.clickCounter) {
    case 1:
      console.log("one");
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log("two");
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log("three");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("not in [1,2,3]");
  }
}); //конец click to btn_refresh
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="review__content__refresh">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: нужно чтобы как в цикле. one-two-three-one-two-three и т. д. Поэтому я подумал, что тут нужен for. Опыта мало. Может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Highmore Можно и в темпе вальса: раз-два-три, раз-два-три. Смотрите добавление в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

Можно еще и так:

```js
'use strict';
function* num() {
  var values = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 3) {
    yield values[i];
    i++
  }
}

function showNext() {
  console.log(iterator.next().value);
}

const iterator = num();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="showNext();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

на native js если интересно с использованием делегирования событий - http://codepen.io/tokamame/pen/rmzzOK?editors=1010

```js
document.addEventListener("load", onLoad());

var but = document.getElementById('button');
var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
var out = document.getElementById('output');
var counter = 1;

function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("click", showClick);
}

function showClick(e) {
  if (e.target.innerHTML === "Кликни меня") {
    out.innerHTML = 'Вы нажали на кнопку "Кликни меня" ' + counter + ' раз';
    counter++;
  } else if (e.target.innerHTML === "Очистить счетчик") {
    out.innerHTML = 'Вы ни разу ни кликали';
    counter = 1;
  } else {
    console.log('Что-то пошло не так');
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Кликни меня</button>
<button id="clear">Очистить счетчик</button>
<div id="output">Вы ни разу ни кликали</div>
```

Comment: Ничто не пошло не так, я просто кликнул мимо кнопки. ;)

Comment: `switch(e.target){case but: ... case clear: ...}` выглядело бы органичнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант)

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let out = document.querySelector('output');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let i = btn.i || 0;
  console.log(`${i%3+1} ticks`)
  btn.i = ++i;
});
```

```html
<button type=button>Click</button>
<output></output>
```

---

С one/two/three:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let out = document.querySelector('output');
let map = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
btn.i = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  btn.i %= 3;
  console.log(map[btn.i++])
});
```

```html
<button type=button>Click</button>
<output></output>
```